# Xpath and tables

Tags: c#, xpath, html-table

This is my first time using XPath queries. I get how it works but I just cant seem to obtain the correct information from this table. I am blaming it on a poorly designed table.

**Xpath path for the table in question** -- /table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]

That path gives me the following information.

```
  <tr>        
    <td style="vertical-align:top">          
    <table style="white-space:nowrap">            
    <tbody>
    <tr>              
      <td style="white-space:nowrap">               
          <span style="font-weight:bold">Norman White</span></td></tr>

 <tr>  
   <td style="white-space:nowrap"> 
     <span style="font-weight:bold">Is Married: </span>Yes</td></tr> <tr>             
   <td style="white-space:nowrap">  
     <span style="font-weight:bold">DOB: </span>birthdate</td></tr><tr> 
 <td style="white-space:nowrap"> 
 <div>     
     <span style="font-weight:bold">SSN: </span>XXX-XX-xxxx</div></td></tr</tbody>table></td>    

    <td style="width:20px">
    <td style="vertical-align:top">
        <table style="white-space:nowrap">
<tbody>
  <tr>  
     <td style="white-space:nowrap"> 
     <span style="font-weight:bold">Lynnea White</span></td></tr> 
 <tr>   
     <td style="white-space:nowrap">
<span style="font-weight:bold">Is Married: </span>Yes</td></tr>
 <tr> 
    <td style="white-space:nowrap">
  <span style="font-weight:bold">DOB: </span>birthdate</td></tr>
<tr> 
 <td style="white-space:nowrap"> 
 <div>  
 <span style="font-weight:bold">SSN: </span>XXX-XX-xxxx</div></td></tr></tbody></table>        </td>        
  <td style="width:20px">      </td></td></tr>
```

I am trying to extract just the two names. 
If i use `table.SelectSingleNode("//table/tbody/tr/td//span").InnerText`, where table is an HTMLNODE containing the code above as `InnerHTML`, then i get the first name "Norman White", but i can't seem to get the second name in any way.

Comment: Would you please format your HTML with correct indentation? Nobody can help you with XPath if your document tree is all on one line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using `SelectNodes` instead of `SelectSingleNode`? :)
([SelectNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hcebdtae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *vs* [SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/h0hw012b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Also, your Xpath may be clearer with something like `//table/tbody/tr[1]//span`. If you don't select the *first* `tr`, it will select all following ones.